# Как проверить наличие пин кода в базе данных и срок его действия?

Tags: php, mysqli

В базе данных в таблице `pin_code` храню пин коды, дату создания и дату завершения действия пин кода.

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM pin_code;
+----------+----------------+---------------------+----------------+
| id       | code           | create_date         | destroy_date   |
+----------+----------------+---------------------+----------------+
|        1 | 6194027126     | 1605500754          | 1607500754     |
|        2 | 5807462325     | 1607808551          | 1609508551     |
+----------+----------------+---------------------+----------------+
```

PHP

```
$visit = time(); // текущее время
$result = mysqli_query( $link, "SELECT * FROM pin_code WHERE code=5807462325 AND destroy_date>$visit;" ); // дата завершения срока действия пин кода должна быть больше текущей
echo mysqli_num_rows( $result );
```

**Все пин коды имеют уникальные значения**.

Не получается корректно проверить из PHP скрипта наличие пин кода в базе и определить действителен код или его время истекло (`create_date` - дата создания кода, `destroy_date` - дата завершения срока действия пин кода).

Как выполнить проверку максимально просто и быстро?

Нужно получить статусы:

- пин код есть или нет
- пин код действителен или просрочен (если он есть в таблице)

Еще хочу поинтересоваться, нет ли смысла хранить даты в базе в другом формате?

Спасибо!

p.s. Похоже я просто пытаюсь найти действующий пин код, а не проверить его на существование и срок действия.

Comment: Добавьте свой код, как вы проверяли наличие и т.п.

Comment: Добавил код, определил текущее время и попробовал сравнить со временем окончания пин кода. Что-то не то делаю, еще и наличие пин кода в базе не проверил изначально...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот твоя ошибка

```
AND destroy_date>$visit;"
```

Сделай так

```
AND destroy_date>'$visit'"
```

Формат даты для этой задачи самый подходящий, не меняй.

> Похоже я просто пытаюсь найти действующий пин код, а не проверить его
> на существование и срок действия

А в чём разница?

Comment: Я хотел еще с помощью php получить статусы: пин код есть или нет, пин код действителен (если он есть) или просрочен, но пока не сообразил как.